# Redux saga router. How to run specific route saga on every match?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

lets say i have such routes:

```
const routes = {
    '/:tab': switchTabGenerator,
    '/users/:id': anotherGenerator 
}
```

Now if i navigate to `/users/:id` route `/:tab` will not be called. But i need this to change selected tab model.
How can i do this ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem. As of now each route has its own generator that executes upon entry right ? Do you want `/users/:id` route to call `/:tab`'s generator also ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, i want `/:tab` to be called always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args) API provided by `redux-saga` can take an array of actions to listen.

```
takeLatest([action.route1, action.route2, action.route3], switchTabGenerator),
```

Pass all the route actions for which you want to trigger the saga.

Comment: Array of actions, but not routes ? I mean what exactly is `action` on your example ?

Comment: `redux-saga` works based on redux actions being fired. Hence if you want route changes to fire the saga, dispatch an action at every change.